# Binding to an object with properties and a list

Tags: model-view-controller, list, binding, properties

I've been able to bind a list of objects correctly. Works fine. Now when I change the item a complex object it stops working.

The complex object is the room name with the list of objects. When the 'postback' the name returns fine, but the list of objects comes back as null.

Any hints please?

Room Model:

```
    public class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }

    public Room() { }
    public Room(string name, List<Option> options)
    {
        Name = name; Options = options;
    }
}
```

Options Model

```
public class Option
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public int UniqueID { get; set; }

    public Option() { }
    public Option(bool isSelected, string imagePath, int uniqueID)
    { IsSelected = isSelected; ImagePath = imagePath; UniqueID = uniqueID; }
}
```

HomeController

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Option> options = new List<Option>();

        options.Add(new Option(true, "../Content/cars_2.jpg", 4));
        options.Add(new Option(true, "../Content/vw_one_liter_concept01_2.jpg", 6));
        options.Add(new Option(false, "../Content/00018578.jpg", 8));
        //Get a list of selected options and union with all remaining

        Room model = new Room("Room1", options);

        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Room model)
    {
        ViewData["results"] = model.Options.Count();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Index View

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MultiSelect.Models.Room>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>

<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Name) %>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("MultiSelect", Model.Options); %>

<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

MultiSelect Partial View

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IList<MultiSelect.Models.Option>>" %>
<% for (int counter = 0;counter< Model.Count(); counter ++)
   { %>
    <div class="opt">
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(i=> i[counter].UniqueID)%>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(i=> i[counter].ImagePath) %>
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i[counter].IsSelected)%>
        <img src="<%= Model.ElementAt(counter).ImagePath %>" alt="Image" width="128" height="128" />
    </div>
<% } %>
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ provides a solution for what you're looking for.

Alternatively, an easier, but less flexible solution is to put a Room.cshtml file, and a Option.cshtml file in your Shared/EditorTemplates folder. Then you'd put

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Name) %>
<% Html.EditorFor(m => m.Options); %>
```

in Room.cshtml

```
<% Html.EditorFor(m => Model); %>
```

in index, and the contents of your partial view in Option.cshtml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Steven Sanderson link shows me how to bind to a list of objects. I was able to do that, but when I changed it to an object that contains a property and a list of objects (parent-children pattern), it returns me the property (parent) but the children are null.