# how to bind to Custom Type with List of objects in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, xmlhttprequest, model-binding

I'm posting the following request to an asp.net-MVC3 application:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:240
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
...
EntityName=Package&Columns[0].Id="Ordering"&Columns[0].Hidden=false&Columns[0].Width="250px"&Columns[1].Id="SubItemId"&Columns[1].Hidden=true&Columns[1].Width="250px"&
```

The following action method is supposed to bind to the form data of the previous request:

```
public ActionResult Scene(GridScene scene) 
{
...
}
```

where GridScene object consists of two properties as follow:

```
public class GridScene
{
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public GridColumns[] Columns { get; set; }
}
```

and GridColumns object consists of three properties as follow:

```
public class GridColumns
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
}
```

The first property (EntityName) is being bound properly, but the GridColumns[] is always null. can anyone help me get it bound ?

PS: Similar Question
[Binding to an object with properties and a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616307/binding-to-an-object-with-properties-and-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !! the problem was related to data encoding. I use JQuery post function to post that request.

the following overload works properly:

```
var data = 'EntityName=Package&Columns[0].Id="Ordering"&Columns[0].Hidden=false&Columns[0].Width="250px"&Columns[1].Id="SubItemId"&Columns[1].Hidden=true&Columns[1].Width="250px"&'
$.post("home/index", data);
```

but this one:

```
$.post("home/index", { scene: data });
```

was sending a URI encoded data, something like that:

```
 ...Columns%5B0%5D.Id%3DUomId%26Columns%5B0%5D.hidden%3Dfalse%26Columns%5B0%5D.width%3D250px%26Columns%5B1%5D.Id%3DOrdering%26Columns%5B1%5D.hidden%3Dfalse%26Columns%5B1%5D.width%3D250px%26
```

which I think confuses the model binder.

I was using that second overload but I couldn't notice the URI encoded data because Chrome developer tools decodes data by default. but using fiddler I managed to find the difference between data sent by each overload.

Hope this may help someone.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried your code on my mvc3 application and it worked fine. I did a get request like this:

Scene?

> EntityName=Package&Columns[0].Id="Ordering"&Columns[0].Hidden=false&Columns[0].Width="250px"&Columns[1].Id="SubItemId"&Columns[1].Hidden=true&Columns[1].Width="250px"

Are you using the default model binder? You should always start from the zero index, cause otherwise the default model binder wont populate your array.